# Updating model data from form value ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I'm very new to ruby on rails. Here i have form

```
<%= form_tag do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :fullname, params[:fullname], placeholder: 'fullname' %>
    .
    .
    .

    <a href="/userEdit"> <%= submit_tag "save" %> </a>
<% end %>
```

Those form is to update model data. In my controller I have

```
def updateUser
    user = Users.find(session[:user_id])
    user.fullname = params[:fullname]
    user.save
    render 'profile'
end
```

It's not working (data doesn't updated), but when I tried

```
def updateUser
    user = Users.find(session[:user_id])
    user.fullname = 'david'
    user.save
    render 'profile'
end
```

It's working (the data updated). I don't know where did I go wrong, please kindly help me. Sorry for asking such easy question, I'm a newbie to Ruby (and so does Rails), I searched but didn't get a suitable answer for this case. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm very new to ruby on rails

Welcome - let me give you some ideas!

--

**Form**

Firstly, your [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) is not created properly. You need to put a route in this (so it knows where to submit the data):

```
<%= form_tag your_path_here do %>
```

This is for the `form_tag` helper, however, as you're editing an object, you'll probably be better using the [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) helper - which takes an actual object (value):

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :full_name %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

This type of form *has* to be used with the `resourceful` structure of Rails, which  is my second point...

--

**Resources**

Rails is built around the idea of a `resourceful` infrastructure (where every data object is a `resource`). If you're updating / editing an object, the typical explanation is that you'll be editing a `resource`, and consequently will want to employ `rails`' [`resourceful` structure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) to handle it:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show]

   def index
       @users = User.all
   end

   def new
       @user = User.new
   end

   def create
       @user = User.new(user_params)
       @user.save
   end

   def edit
   end

   def update
      @user.update(user_params)
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:fullname, :etc)
   end

   def set_user
       @user = User.find params[:id]
   end

end
```

This will allow you to define the [`resourceful` routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) for this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users
```

Using this setup with `form_for` will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Didn't notice in the beginning. Your form is incorrect. You did not specify a URL for action, and you put your submit tag within a link so basically your link is getting called not your form submitted.

```
<%= form_tag '/userEdit' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :fullname, params[:fullname], placeholder: 'fullname' %>
    .
    .
    .

    <%= submit_tag "save" %>
<% end %>
```

Make sure that you have specified a route for userEdit post method.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped my question. Actually I assign user.fullname = params[:fullname] But it's not working

Comment: I will modify my reply

Comment: Thank you very much. I've found my mistake. It's routing error, When I restarted rails server it says "no route match post..."

Comment: No problem, do you know how to fix that?